# No performance with pragma omp for

Tags: c, gcc, openmp

I'm start learn the OpenMP, uses for parallel computing, and I test the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int i,j,k,a = -59, b = 19,N,R;      
    struct timeval T1, T2;
        long delta_ms;

        N = atoi(argv[1]);
    float m1[N][N], m2[N][N], m3[N][N];

    gettimeofday(&T1, NULL); 


    #pragma omp parallel for default(none) private(R,i,j,k) shared(N,b,a,m1, m2, m3)
    for (R=0; R<100; R++) 
        {
        srand(R);

        #pragma omp parallel for default(none) private(i,j) shared(N,b,a,m1)
        for (i = 0; i < N; i++){
            for (j = 0; j < N; j++){
                m1[i][j] = (float) rand() / RAND_MAX * (b - a + 1) + a;
            }
        }

        #pragma omp parallel for default(none) private(i,j) shared(N,m1,m2)
        for (i = 0; i < N; i++){
            for (j = 0; j < N; j++){
                m2[i][j] = m1[i][j] * 5;  
            }
        }

        #pragma omp parallel for default(none) private(i,j,k) shared(N,m1,m2,m3)
        for(i = 0; i < N; i++){
            for(j = 0; j < N; j++){
                m3[i][j] = 0;
                for(k = 0; k < N; k++){
                    m3[i][j] = m3[i][j] + (m1[i][k] * m2[k][j]);
                }
            }
        }


        }
    gettimeofday(&T2, NULL);
    delta_ms = 1000*(T2.tv_sec - T1.tv_sec) + (T2.tv_usec - T1.tv_usec)/1000;
    printf("\nN=%d. Milliseconds passed: %ld\n", N, delta_ms);
    return 0;
}
```

the characteristics of my computer:

I use the virtual machine (Virtual Box). I installed the Ubuntu 14.04. My virtual machine uses the 3 CPU's and 1 Gb RAM. I use the gcc compiler, version 4.8

Now I have the big interest by the following situation:

1. I compile my code with no `-fopenmp` key: `gcc -o code1 code1.c`.

When I run the code1 and I see:

```
N=300. Milliseconds passed: 13706
```

2. I compile my code with key `-fopenmp`: `gcc -o code1 code1.c -fopenmp`.

When I run the code1 and I see:

```
N=300. Milliseconds passed: 4898
```

3. I compile my code with key `-fopenmp` and I use only one `#pragma omp for`:

`#pragma omp parallel for default(none) private(R,i,j,k) shared(N,b,a,m1, m2, m3) 
for (R=0; R<100; R++) 
{...}`

When I run the code1 and I see:

```
N=300. Milliseconds passed: 4919
```

The results from steps 2 and 3 are equals.

Can anybody explain to me why this is happening?

I read documentation by OpenMP, but I doesn't find the answer.

Comment: `srand()` and `rand()` are not thread safe. Both of them touch global variables. Such a race condition can easily kill performance. (on top of being a correctness issue)

Comment: @Mysticial thak you for your comment. Yes, I had not thought about it, so did not notice.

Comment: AFAICS you can't parallelize the R loop, every single iteration there is accessing the same arrays!

Comment: @JimCownie thank for comment. Can you explain me, why every single iteration there is accessing the same arrays?

Comment: Because none of the indices into your m[1..3] arrays depend on R. So each iteration of the R loop is updating the same store locations.

Answer (score 0):

Check the [OMP_NUM_THREADS](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libgomp/OMP_005fNUM_005fTHREADS.html) environment variable. I had this problem once with VirtualBox, and the problem was that this variable was set to 1.
It should be equal with the number of CPU cores (or x2 if you use hypethreading).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I checked this variable. The value of variable is equal number of CPU.

Comment: I have not had this problem with VirtualBox. When you set up a virtual machine you need to go to settings, then processor, and select the number of CPUs. I set it to the number of Hyper-Threads. Virtual Box warns me that I should should use the number of physical CPUs. I don't know if that's better with VirtualBox but then I never use VirtualBox for performance anyway.